# Can I use AWS AppSync with self-hosted PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-appsync

For example, I have a Linux server with a PostgreSQL server installed. How can I integrate it with AWS AppSync? 
Or can I only use Amazon RDS for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a lambda datasource which can talk to your postgreSQL server on your self hosted EC2 instance. If you go to AWS AppSync console, it has a sample which uses RDS, but you can easily point that to PostgreSQL database, & so long as the lambda function and the linux server are deployed to the same VPC it should work.

[Here](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-appsync-rds-aurora-sample) is the sample on Github.